# Using win32api within a WSGI

Tags: python, winapi, wsgi

I'm creating a Flask app that controls another program using the pypiwin32 module. I can run it fine in development mode, but once I need to pass it through a WSGI, things get complicated. I tried setting up uWSGI through Cygwin, but pypiwin32 cannot be installed. I looked into mod_wsgi but installing that in Windows looks complicated with having to juggle C compilers.

Most likely I will be using nginx as my gateway, however nothing is set in stone.

Any suggestions on a tech stack that will let me run a WSGI while calling the win32api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing a pure python WSGI solution called [waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/), simply because it's easily compatible with Windows (unlike gunicorn, which would have been my choice).